# Laravel Migration table not created

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am a new learner of Laravel.And I follow the tutorial to create a articles table.Here's part of my code in /database/migrations/2017_02_13_145946_create_article_table.php

```
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('articles', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->string('title');
       $table->text('body')->nullable();
       $table->integer('user_id');
       $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

When I run `php artisan migrate` the table was not created.I googled the problem and ran `php artisan migrate:reset` command to delete all the tables.When I ran `php artisan migate` command again.It shows

```
Migrated: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated: 2017_02_13_145946_create_article_table
```

But nothing was created but only updated the record of migrations table.The table `user` and `password_resets` was also not created.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: if it show you migration successful message then the table must be created, did you check the migrations table in your database to verify the record exist ..

Comment: @AkramWahid I had checked the migrations table.Column ID did increased.But the other two tables were not generated.

Comment: can you show me an screenshot for your migration table

Answer (score 6):

### It is because of Table column(values) length is by default 1071 which not accept by mysql

To clear this problem go to **mysql** and delete all the *tables*.
Go to your application(project) folder => app => Providers

write this on top of your `AppServiceProvider.php` file.

```
//edit:yrs:- Needed for edit
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

write this inside the boot method

```
//edit:yrs:-we can edit column sizefor tables here
Schema::defaultStringLength(150);
```

then come to console and execute the

---

*command />`php artisan migrate:status` and see the run status is y or n if it is n then execute

```
*command />`php artisan migrate`

*command />`php artisan migrate:status` and then 

*command />`php artisan migrate:refresh` and then 

*command />`php artisan migrate:status`
```

that's all your done with createing with tables in **mysql**

Answer (score 1):

I normally try several things:

1. In the console do rollbacks till you get 'nothing to rollback':

   `php artisan migrate:rollback`
2. Then, check your article migration file and look for down function (if you haven't one you need to add it)

   `public function down()
   {
       // Drop articles table
       Schema::drop('articles');
   }`
3. Save your migration article file(I know it sounds dumb, but it happened to me before). I would recommend to change the name of the file also, from:

   *2017_02_13_145946_create_article_table.php*, to:

   *2017_02_13_145946_create_**articles**_table.php*
4. Use:

   `composer dump-autoload`
5. Go to your database(laravel_db in this case) and check if there are any table(Mysql Console):

   `show databases;
   use laravel_database:
   show tables;`
6. If there are not any table but migrations, delete it using:

   `drop table migrations;`
7. Once you have the database empty, run the migrations from console:

   `php artisan migrate`
8. Finally, if not errors being trowed, check the tables created(Mysql Console):

   `show tables;`

Comment: Thanks for you reply!I had recreated the project and the problem is gone.